# On the category page, get the category object

Tags: categories, template-tags

Right, hopefully a nice and simple one... I'm on a category page with the id of 4, I want to get the category object back so I can interogate a few values.

I've had a good old look in the WP codex with little success, remember I don't want to get the categories from a post, I want the category object from the current category.

Many thanks,
Ben :-)

Comment: You should vote up Fernandos answer and check it as the sollution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the category object use `get_category` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category)). It's easy if you know the name, slug or ID, but if you don't you could use `is_category` to check on which category you are and pass the ID to `get_category`.

Comment: This doesn't actually make sense. In fact, this is the only response that ISN'T a correct answer. The OP wanted a way to get the cat object. is_category doesn't "check on which category you are" - it tells you IF you're on a category page. If you have the ID, then yeah you can use get_category(), but I'm assuming here that the OP was using ID=4 as an arbitrary example, but actually wouldn't know beforehand the ID of the cat he wanted to query.

Comment: This isn't a correct answer...! As you wrot Tom.

Answer (score 15):

Damn, so I did find the answer I was looking for:

```
$thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
```

Never mind :-)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 7):

`$wp_query->get_queried_object()` is a very versatile function. It will return the current category, tag, custom taxonomy term, author, page or post, depending on the page/archive you are viewing. Especially handy if you want to [simplify your archive headings](http://yoast.com/get-queried-object/).

Answer (score 4):

I'd personally get into a habit of calling `get_term` or `get_terms`, as the category functions are only wrapper functions that in turn call `get_term(s)` anyway.

```
<?php 
$queried_category = get_term( get_query_var('cat'), 'category' ); 

// echo $queried_category->term_id; // The category ID
// echo $queried_category->slug; // The category slug
// echo $queried_category->name; // The category name 
// echo $queried_category->description; // The category description 
?>
```

Familiaring yourself with the term functions will make dealing with custom taxonomies a little easier, because you'll be calling on these functions in such cases.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

And a function that i don't see used a great deal, but can be really handy.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by
Which provides a means of fetching a term object based on name, slug or ID.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting case wherein one of many category archive pages included in a custom menu returned an empty array for

```
get_the_category();
```

required me to run through all the different ways to skin a cat (no pun intended).

```
is_category() RETURNS true
get_the_category() RETURNS an empty array
the_category() RETURNS NULL
```

The final answer ended up being [Ben Everard](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/29/ben-everard)'s

```
 get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false) RETURNS the correct WPCategory object
```

Thanks!

Comment: actually, @JanFabry's answer is the one here which should be marked "correct" - [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object), much simpler, and the preferred method.